# Type-safe Chained Generics

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to do this:

> `public <A, B> B pipe(A a)`

Such that I can verify the types of chained method calls, to get:

> `pipe<A, B>  -->`
>      `pipe<B, C>  -->`
>      `pipe<C, D>  -->`

With an arbitrary number of `pipe()` calls?

Or is this impossible to do?

Comment: Have you tried anything or just posted the question? If the former, please show your code in form of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Can you show actual Java code that you are trying to develop?

Comment: Show how you would like to use the method (even if it doesnt compile) if such a thing were possible.

Comment: Surely you can do this. Share your code if its not working

Comment: Generics are checked at compile time, so "arbitrary number" should also be available at compile time, and not just a number, but each pipe() call.